# In VB for loops is less that or greater than allowed?

Tags: vb6, for-loop

eg code

```
        For lLngIndex = 0 To lLngIndex < 256 Step 1
            lBytKeyAry(lLngIndex) = Val(pStrKey((lLngIndex Mod lLngKeyLength)))
        Next
```

is lLngIndex < 256 allowed?

when I debug code and go step by step it seems to always skip the for loops

Comment: Do you mean `For lLngIndex = 0 To 255 Step 1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct code for loop:

```
For lLngIndex = 0 To 255
    lBytKeyAry(lLngIndex) = Val(pStrKey((lLngIndex Mod lLngKeyLength)))
Next
```

NOTE: No need for step 1 because step 1 is the default value

Comment: Thanks :) but as an example, can one use this:   For i = 0 to i > value ?

Comment: oh wait I think I understand now, it goes from i to i something eg For i =0 to value right?

Comment: Most questions i asked on this didnt give me the right answer I was looking for. But thank you for your help :)